# Can I use/import kotlin multi-platform library in ios/android native projects directly?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to build a cross-platform library for both ios and android native projects. The library will contain just some business logic nothing related to the UI, sort of how the KMM is structured.

If I built a KMM plugin, KMM projects can use it, but can the ios/android native projects import and use them as well?

Edit: Consider the consumer of the library is just a native ios app and not a KMM project. I do not want to suggest them to convert their project to a KMM project.

If yes would you please share any example libraries?

If no are there any other solutions I can use to build a library to support all different projects android/ios/KMM?

Comment: The examples seem to use KMM structure, let's say if the user of the library is only trying to use it in IOS native application that has no KMM would it be easy to integrate without converting the whole application to KMM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including a KMM module into an existing iOS app does not require any sort of conversion of the existing iOS app. The KMM shared component can be developed on its own, and included in the iOS project by adding it in the iOS project's podfile, then methods from it can be called like any other third-party library. You can find more about KMM CocoaPods integration [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods.html#update-podfile-for-xcode).

```
# this is the only change needed in the iOS project (in the podfile)
pod 'mymodule', :path => '/path/to/kmm/project'
```

In the KMM project itself, you would configure the iOS target in the gradle file and point it back at the iOS project. There are more details about this [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods.html#add-a-dependency-between-a-kotlin-pod-and-xcode-project-with-one-target)

```
kotlin {
    ios()

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Core library summary"
        homepage = "https://www.myproject.com"

        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.0"
        podfile = project.file("/path/to/ios/project/podfile")
    }

    //...
}
```

There are a lot of KMM [samples](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-samples.html) available in addition to the documentation above, and some details [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-create-first-app.html) about how to create a KMM project in Android Studio.

Comment: Do you have the solution to integrate the library as a "regular framework"?

Comment: Did you find a working solution for this ?